# ui-router controller stateparams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following usecase:
I have two views which are identical, as well as two controllers which are very similar. I intend to extend one controller with the other and just override the diff. The problem I am having is in ui-router I want to choose a controller by name (Since the templates is shared, and the controllers differ this cannot be declared in the template itself)

Before this refactoring I had the following code:

```
.state('edit-page-menu', {
           url: '/sites/:siteId/page_menus/:menuId',
           templateUrl: 'partials/edit-menu.html',
           controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', (scope, stateParams) => {
               scope.siteId = stateParams.siteId
               scope.menuId = stateParams.menuId
           }]
       })
```

Which adds the stateParams to the scope. In this usecase I had the controller defined in the template and could modify the scope that way. However now when I switch to controller by name approach

```
.state('edit-page-menu', {
           url: '/sites/:siteId/menus/:menuId',
           templateUrl: 'partials/edit-menu.html',
           controller: 'editMenuCtrl'
       })
```

I don't know how to inject / add the $stateParams to the controller. And I would really like to avoid injecting "$state" in the controller and fetch the parameters that way. Is there a way to modify the scope of a controller if you choose it by name?

Best regards.

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking or what the specific problem is. Show us current structure for registering your `editMenuCtrl` controller

Comment: The controller works fine and is registered in a module:

`.controller('editMenuCtrl', EditMenuController)`

the problem is not loading the controller, but passing the $stateParams to it when referring to it by name. I want to avoid:

injecting $state in the controller and do something along the following lines:
`this.scope.menuId = $state.params.menuId
this.scope.siteId = $state.params.siteId`

Comment: why can't you do injection? Also can use `$stateParams`. Alternative is use `resolve` in state config. `I don't want to` doesn't outline a specific problem

Comment: Well since I have maybe 20+ other routes which have all their properties injected in their scope in the ui-routing file. I don't want variables to be injected from the $state in the controller but rather have 1 file to look in to determine what routing properties a specific controller needs. The `I don't want to` part is basically me wanting to keep configuration in one place.